# Facebook auto respond to like button

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-like

I'd like people to receive a message in their inbox when they like my fanpage, and i'm wondering what's the best way to go about this?

I don't know if I can use the SDK to do it because there's no guarantee they will be viewing a canvas when they actually click the like button.  They could be clicking the like button from the side bar, from a friend's page, from the official page wall, etc.

Other ideas?

Answer (score 1):

This article describes how to capture a click on the **Like** button:
http://www.saschakimmel.com/2010/05/how-to-capture-clicks-on-the-facebook-like-button/

However, the only way to get someone's email address is by asking the user to authorize the **email** permission.

Comment: The problem is my code wouldn't be running if someone likes the page from any place other than the canvas.  For instance the wall.  Also by Inbox I meant their messages

Comment: You can't send messages to users automatically. Messages can only be sent with a facebook dialog which requires user interaction.